# Why we need transactional guarantees for Kafka eos

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Now that idempotent producer can provide the exactly once guarantee for **every** TopicPartition, why do we need transactions to provide guarantees for writes across multiple TopicPartitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idempotent producer only guarantees exactly once semantics for each **individual** Produce request it sends. Each idempotent request can succeed or fail and they are all independent.

On the other side, transactions allows to **group several requests** (potentially to many partitions and on many brokers) to be all treated as a group. So when committing the transaction, either all of them will be successful or all of them will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe I need to update my understanding of eos